# How to Generate an 3 channels image like that done by Exporting as PNG with ColorMapLength option

Tags: image-processing

```
data=Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[
Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/67lQS.png"],"Byte"]]]];
img=Image[data]
```

This is the sample image names `img` that we can Imported that into Wolfram Mathematica.

The final image which I want is done by `Export["imgFinal.png", img, "ColorMapLength" -> 200];`

As we can see in the HelpPage of `PNG`, `ColorMapLength` option does some `Color Quantization`  manipulation

So, my question is how can I get the `imgFinal=Import["imgFinal.png"]` without by `Import`, something like by `imgFinal=ColorQuantilize[img]`?

And further, 'imgFinalNew.png`got by`Export["imgFinalNew.png",imgFinal]`without Options(by default options) should be the same with`Export["imgFinal.png", img, "ColorMapLength" -> 200];`

If we directly do `ColorQuantilize[img]`, the image channel is 1, the final image I need should have 3 channels.

```
imgFinal001 = Import[Export["test.png", img, "ColorMapLength" -> 100]]
img0 = Image[data, ColorSpace -> "RGB"]
imgFinal002 = ColorQuantize[img0, 100]
ImageAdjust@ImageDifference[imgFinal002,imgFinal001]
```

[image]

Comment: If I do `Information@ColorQuantize@Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7DJS.png"` it tells me that the quantized image has 3 channels - is this not what you want?

Comment: @LukasLang  See update, the image from the data would get 1-channel image by `ColorQuantize`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to explicitly specify a [`ColorSpace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorSpace.html) in order to prevent `ColorQuantize` from converting the image to grayscale:

```
img = Image[data, ColorSpace -> "RGB"]

ColorQuantize@img
```

[image]

If you want to reproduce the behavior of `Export` exactly, you need to convert the image to data type `"Byte"`:

```
ColorQuantize[Image[Image[data], "Byte", ColorSpace -> "RGB"], 100]
```

[image]

```
ImageAdjust@ImageDifference[
  ColorQuantize[Image[Image[data], "Byte", ColorSpace -> "RGB"], 100],
  ImportString[ExportString[img, "PNG", "ColorMapLength" -> 100], "PNG"]
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: Glad to know the Option of ColorSpace in Image, it's useful.  There is one further question is the `img` is not the same like that done by export, see my update.

Comment: @HyperGroups Please see the update

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need. Funny to use `Image[Image[data]]`, sometimes I Use `Image[ImageData[img]]` which is no need then.